# simple text input dialogebox

Tags: c#, input, dialog

VB programmers know that there was an *inputbox* dialoge box for asking user to simply input an string.
I'm just curious that if there is any similar in C# or I have to use a designed form?

tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the visual basic function:

```
string returnVal = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter a string", "Title", "", -1, -1);
```

Comment: This is not working for me. It says Interaction does not exist in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace for VS 2010.

Comment: You have to import Microsoft.Visualbasic into your references, then it will work as explained.

Answer (score 1):

The same method still exists in VB.NET!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z0ak68w%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: I know, I didn't ask for VB. I asked for its existence in .Net! C# maybe!

Comment: @MBZ C# is to .NET as Square is to Rectangle.

Comment: I become too crappy, Updated Q.